# Bash - выбор из файла

Tags: bash

Ребят, помогите pls. Исходные данные - есть файл, 123.txt вида:

```
1:test123a  
2:test234f  
3:test345h  
4:test456u  
5:test678v  
6:test789e  
7:test890v  
8:test098t  
9:test987g  
10:test876i  
11:test756f  
12:test645s  
13:test543d  
14:test432y
```

есть файлы, вида:

```
./1111/test123a.sh  
./1111/test234f.sh  
./1111/test345h.sh  
./1111/test456u.sh  
./1111/test678v.sh  
./1111/test789e.sh  
./1111/test890v.sh  
./1111/test098t.sh  
./1111/test987g.sh  
./1111/test876i.sh  
./1111/test756f.sh  
./1111/test645s.sh  
./1111/test543d.sh  
./1111/test432y.sh
```

нужно сделать скрипт, который при подаче на вход цифры сравнивал ее с цифрой до двоеточия в файле 123.txt, находил скрипт с именем после двоеточия и выполнял этот скрипт.

Новичок в линуксе, второй день никак не могу придумать как можно такую выборку сделать... Спасибо!!!

Comment: вы же уже разбили одну большую задачу на подзадачи. начинайте их реализовывать последовательно. возникнут конкретные вопросы — задавайте.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! За два дня у вас же есть какие то варианты? представьте их нам. Не стестняейтесь, это нормально ошибаться, но за вас вряд ли кто то будет выполнять работу. Мы посмотрим, подкоректируем, посоветуем. Добвьте больше информации в [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1286688/edit)

Comment: Спасиб, ребят! Все заработало, причем обоими способами :)

Answer (score 3):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#входящий параметр
number=${1}
#либо можно предложить пользователю ввести номер вручную
#для использования раскоментировать следующую строку
#read -p "Введите цифру: " number

#Проверка что введена цифра/ы
[[ ${number:-null} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { 
   echo "Можно вводить только цифры, выходим"
   exit
}
#Получаем имя скрипта с цифрой
#Выбираем последнюю запись на случай, если было несколько строк с данной цифрой ограничиваемся последней записью
scriptName=`grep -oP "(?<=^$number:).*" 123.txt | tail -n1`

#Запускаем скрипт
$scriptName
```

Answer (score 3):

Скрипт `cmd.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=`grep -P '^'$1':' 123.txt | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`
bash "$FILE.sh"
```

Пример использования: `./cmd.sh 2`. Файл 123.txt должен быть в текущем каталоге. И не забудьте `chmod +x ./cmd.sh` чтобы работало.

Разберем по порядку

1. `grep -P '^'$1':' 123.txt` - в `$1` содержится переданный аргумент (2), далее поиск по регулярке в файле значения `^2:`.
2. `cut -d: -f2` отрезает по разделителю "двоеточие" и берет вторую часть
3. `awk '{print $1}'` - в файле есть пробелы, эта часть отрезает из
4. `bash "$FILE.sh"` - запуск на выполнение.